# Why is the one-point compactification of the rationals sequentially compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

The problem is:
Let $\Bbb Q^* = \Bbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\Bbb Q$. Is this sequentially compact? 
 
 A solution makes reference to $\Bbb Q^*$ being a sequentially compact space but without a proof, but wouldn't any sequence of rationals converging to an irrational have no convergent subsequence in $\Bbb Q^*$? How does this fail to be a counterexample? 
 Note that in this course we haven't studied first countable sets or anything to do with that. And thank you!

Comment: HINT: Your sequence converges to $\infty$ for the same reason that the sequence $\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\infty$. What are the only subsets of those two sequences that are compact in the space $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think finite subsets of ℚ∗ are compact. No infinite subset without ∞ which has a limit point in ℝ lying in ℝ∖ℚ will be compact (using an argument like jMdA in comments) and sets that get arbitrarily large without ∞ are compact either. Everything else is compact. So if we have a rational sequence which would converge in ℝ to an irrational, it converges to ∞ in ℚ∗because all neighbourhoods of infinity include an infinite number of points of the sequence. Same for ⟨:∈ℕ⟩.

Comment: That’s right; it sounds like you have the right basic idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What is the topology on $\mathbb{Q}^*$? What does a neighborhood of $\infty$ look like? It's not at all what it would be in the case of $\mathbb{R}$.

Further Hint: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact, so the one point compactification is not Hausdorff.

Comment: could you explain why $\mathbb Q$ is not locally compact?

Comment: @Targon Because $\mathbb{Q}\cap (x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$ is not compact for $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: are we talking about the discrete topology?

Comment: @Targon Intuitively speaking, there are points missing from any neighborhood of $\mathbb{Q}$. You can construct an infinite set of opens around any irrational that cannot be reduced to a finite subcover. Take an increasing and decreasing sequence $a_n$ and $b_n$ that converge to the same irrational, then $[a_n, b_n]^C$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{Q}$ that doesn't admit a finite subcover, because of the "hole" at $r$.

Comment: @Targon It's also not the discrete topology. No infinite set is compact with the discrete topology.

Comment: very cool argument, never thought of that. thank you

Comment: @jMdA Neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the sets $\{ \infty\} \cup V$ where $\Bbb Q \backslash V$ is a closed compact set in $\Bbb Q$. And, I think the compact sets in $\Bbb Q$ are the sets that have accumulation points in $\Bbb Q$ or are finite? Is this right? I did find that $\Bbb Q^*$ wasn't Hausdorff but am not sure how that factors in.

Comment: @Doodle Correct. So to answer your initial question. The accumulation point of a collection of rational points that has an irrational accumulation point in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$. To prove this space is sequentially compact, you can use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is sequentially compact. If the convergent subsequence has a rational limit, the limit in $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is the same rational, otherwise it's the point $\infty$.